# Known Bug on Zurb Foundation ? large-2 Columns x 6 = 100.0002%

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation, percentage

In foundation, `width` of the `large-2 columns` is `16.6667%`

scene-1: When creating six `large-2 columns` inside a `row`, the total `width` becomes `100.0002%`
It is not noticeable for human eye. However it isn't seems to be pure for a web designers and the standard wise its a very confusion.

scene-2: When creating two `large-6 columns` inside another `row`, the total width is pure `100%` which is correct and perfect.

when I'm placing these two rows one beneath the other the widths are seems very equal.

1. My questions are: Does foundation use some special method for the
   scene-1 to avoid go beyond 100%. if there is I need to know how?
2. Or is this a common bug happen when designing grid based layouts? and always layout become less or excess in desired `width`?

Comment: since monitors are restricted to whole pixels they will round to display the the nearest pixel instead of always rounding up. if it is 100.002% then it will round down and display at 100% since it cannot display a .002%